# Capture UICollectionView Screenshot with contentInset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am facing strange problem with UICollectionView. I need to show spacing in collection view from all the directions and with the help of given below line i am able to make it.

```
self.collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topSpacing,leftSpacing,bottomSpacing,rightSpacing);
```

When i capture the screenshot it goes to the minus of left and top pixels. But on the devices screen collection view always show correct with spacing all sides.
[Captured Screenshot from Xcode Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4TWU.png)

Comment: Please share the screenshot for the better explanation.

Comment: @Imad please look now, Sorry for not looking the posted question properly.